# What do people use instead of the discontinued weather-indicator in 13.04?

Tags: indicator, weather

The `weather-indicator` package have been removed from Ubuntu 13.04 (it crashed all the time and did not display forecasts).

What is the replacement package?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best is my-weather-indicator for atareo https://launchpad.net/~atareao/+archive/atareao

Answer (score 10):

I've stepped in as maintainer of the Weather Indicator project, and just pushed a new release that fixes the Forecast issue and most (if not all) of the crash bugs.

Try it out: https://launchpad.net/~weather-indicator-team/+archive/ppa

Comment: I'm getting a dependency issue: python-pywapi (>=0.3.2)

Comment: @duxk.gh: install the newest version from the PPA above, or from the pywapi PPA here: https://launchpad.net/~pywapi-devel/+archive/ppa

Answer (score 1):

I've found **my-weather-indicator** too buggy (displaying only N/A in 4-day forecasts, unable to use Yahoo Weather, etc.), and therefore decided (at least for now) to use **ClearWeather** instead, although it's not an **indicator**, but a **screenlet**, included in the **screenlets-pack-all** package.

**UPDATE:** The bugs mentioned above have been **fixed** as of version **0.6.4** (end May 2013) and therefore there's no more need to use more memory-hungry Screenlets daemon to merely display a couple of weather forecasts on desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [Cairo Dock](http://www.glx-dock.org/) will do. It has weather dock and other useful stuff. Small and simple.